# Debugging customer session issues... tools?

Tags: magento2, debugging

We periodically run into issues on our M2.2.3 website, where customer cannot seem to complete their checkout process (spinning circle for example).

It has been a nightmare to try and debug these issues since no server-side logs are generated for certain kinds of problems (and many customers refuse to want to help us debug the problem... I cannot blame them in that case).

I'm wondering if anybody knows of an extension that works something like the [Advanced Template Hints module](https://github.com/ho-nl/magento2-Ho_Templatehints) that would allow our tech support (while talking to the customer) add a url key, that would then dump a much greater debug detail to the customer/or server for further debugging.

This would be extremely helpful, but its a problem I've been struggling with for years with M2.

Comment: Most of the problems we had wit this kind of issues was related to google analytics issues : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12428

Answer (score 0):

Most of the issues that come in magento checkout are mainly in ko js or failing API calls to register checkout data to magento backend.

Either of these can be even difficult for dev to debug, let alone a regular customer.

But anyway there are couple of tools you can use to check these;

1. Network panel of chrome dev console to check for failed API calls
2. KO context debugger - 
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof
   It will help you to debug ko issues.

But, I highly doubt any regular customer would be able to make sense of any of these tools.